# SQL Server Foreign Key references invalid Table 'employees'

Tags: sql-server

I try to run this SQL Server query:

```
USE DB_UBB;

CREATE TABLE dept_emp (
    emp_no      INT         NOT NULL,
    dept_no     CHAR(4)     NOT NULL,
    from_date   DATE        NOT NULL,
    to_date     DATE        NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (emp_no) REFERENCES employees(emp_no) ON DELETE CASCADE, -- Error here
    FOREIGN KEY (dept_no) REFERENCES departments(dept_no) ON DELETE CASCADE, -- And here
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no, dept_no)
);
CREATE INDEX (emp_no);
CREATE INDEX (dept_no);
```

and I get these errors:

```
Foreign key 'FK__dept_emp__8bc6840bee39d6cef4bd' references invalid table 'employees'.

Foreign key 'fk__dept_emp__99bc0b2304d3f32059a9' references invalid table 'departments'.
```

even though I have these tables:

[image: Departments]

[image: Employees]

What do I do wrong?

---

*EDIT:*

Added Whole DB:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the screen shots are from `DB_UBB` database

Comment: Yes. I will update with whole db right now.

Comment: Try writing schema along with table. E.g instead of using employees use dbo.employees

Comment: I tried that as well and it didn't work. I used MSSQL before but it never did these stuff before.

Comment: the problem is with your indexes .sql server will create culstor index againstr your primary .

Comment: Looks like it should work to me. I never use the `on delete` clause, try it without that? (Also a minor suggestion: name the constraints, e.g. `...CONSTRAINT FK_dept_emp__departments FOREIGN KEY (dept_no) <etc>`, it will make them easier to manage in the long run.

Comment: I'll be home in 2h. Gonna check all solutions then

Comment: Still no go. Doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

SQL ‘hides’ the columns from the Key of the `Clustered` Index in `Nonclustered` Indexes.
You have created a composite primary on both `emp_no,dept_no`

cluster index of primary will hide both columns from indexes in following queries and will generate error

```
CREATE INDEX (emp_no);
CREATE INDEX (dept_no);
```

Comment: Still don't get what I should do. I removed the create index and still error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifying the foreign key after the column specifications, try using the CONSTRAINT clause instead:

```
to_date     DATE      NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_dept_emp_dept FOREIGN KEY (emp_no) REFERENCES employees(emp_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT fk_dept_emp_emp FOREIGN KEY (dept_no) REFERENCES departments(dept_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
```

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same error occurs. I will try to restart my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Aparently, I even though the tables were created, it didn't recognize them.

I added an `<if not exist, create tables>`

I also removed the `CREATE INDEX (emp_no);` and `CREATE INDEX (dept_no);` as @Muhammad Nasir said, but it didn't fix the referencing issue.

Solution:

```
USE DB_UBB;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE name='employees' and xtype='U')
    CREATE TABLE employees (
        emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
        birth_date  DATE            NOT NULL,
        first_name  VARCHAR(14)     NOT NULL,
        last_name   VARCHAR(16)     NOT NULL,
        gender      VARCHAR(1)      NOT NULL CHECK (gender IN('M', 'F')),
        hire_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (emp_no)
    );
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE name='departments' and xtype='U')
    CREATE TABLE departments (
        dept_no     CHAR(4)         NOT NULL,
        dept_name   VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (dept_no),
        UNIQUE (dept_name)
    );
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE name='dept_emp' and xtype='U')
CREATE TABLE dept_emp (
    emp_no      INT         NOT NULL,
    dept_no     CHAR(4)     NOT NULL,
    from_date   DATE        NOT NULL,
    to_date     DATE        NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (emp_no) REFERENCES employees(emp_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (dept_no) REFERENCES departments(dept_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no, dept_no)
);
GO
```